# Can "thing" refer to a group (plural)?

Tags: grammatical-number

Consider the following sentence:

> People are the most valuable thing a computer has ever encountered.

Since "people" is plural, should I use "things" instead of "thing"?

Comment: I am fine with _thing_ being used to refer to _people_. The notion of computers _seeing_ things is more sketchy to me.

Comment: I guess I could use _perceived_, _observed_, or _encountered_. What I'm trying to convey is a sentient computer which has a list of all objects it has encountered. It considers some objects more valuable or useful than others, and people are at the top of that list.

Comment: I would definitely use _encounter_ in that context.

Comment: The statement is almost an oxymoron. Or maybe a tautology. Since people design computers, a computer's "value system" (if it could be said to have one) is necessarily installed by humans. And since most computers interact only with humans, what would computers have to compare against humans?

Comment: Or are we really talking about sci-fi androids (e.g. Commander Data on Star Trek TNG, who finds humans "fascinating")?

Comment: @brian. It's the latter that I'm trying to convey. I spend most of my day programming computers. Usually we think of the computer as a tool for us. However, I could think of myself as a "Human Processing Unit" which the computer uses in the same way that it uses an FPU or GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is not about whether computers can see people, but does English use 'things' or 'thing' for 'people'? That is, is the term 'people' singular or plural?  I think technically it is singular, but in general usage it tends to be used as if it is plural. That is much like the term 'team'.  I think we tend to think of a noun that describes a group of things as plural even if the grammar books would tell us it is supposed to be singular.  So, I think most native English speakers would say 'things' if they were referring to 'people' in this way.  But also, of course, if you are saying 'people are ...' You need to use 'things'. If you are saying 'thing' then you need to say 'people is ...', which sounds weird to me.

Comment: Thanks, Irene--it's the grammar I'm interested in. So I can use 'People are the most valuable things...' or 'People is the most valuable thing...' Is that right?